# Android "Valid XML document must have a root tag at line"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Before asking this question, I searched goole and so as well but I could not found any help.
The code looks well but I am unable to understand the error

`Valid XML document must have a root tag at line 15.`

Please have a look to the attached image.
[image]

any help will be much appreciated.

Additional:

I have analyzed code many times. But still getting the following:
[image]
Thanks in advance.
Iqbal

Comment: what happens if u remove the tools context

Comment: @PulkitSethi No effect, same result.

Comment: i dont think u should have xmlns:android in the view pager cant confirm dont have comp please remove and check

Comment: @PulkitSethi I have to use that, I am following the tutorial [Android Tab Layout](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

Comment: u need that in relative layout not the viewpager

Comment: or u can just remove the relativelayout

Comment: remove the xmlns from the second control. You only need to set it on the root control (RelativeLayout)

Comment: @PulkitSethi strange even i removed the relative tag, still it shows the same error. I think it might be Android Studio issue.

Comment: @Vyger I did that, no effect same result.

Comment: I can see no other errors. Do a Project/Clean. If still not enough, do a File/Restart.

Comment: @Vyger I did clean but no luck. Actually when I build the project it runs but when I click on second tab it raise Unexpected Error. So I started to see the code and I found this error. Its very strange.

Comment: what if you remove </android.support....> line and just close the tag so:  />

Comment: Thanks @Vyger doing so error disappeared. +1

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `</android.support....>` line and just close the tag so: `/>`

Comment: May I ask the downvoter the reason for downvoting? If the answer has been accepted, I think it doesn't deserve a -1.